# Inter process communication by tcp 127.0.0.1 on the same node very slow

Tags: networking, server, client

Tcp communication very slow by 127.0.0.1 or eth IP(eg:10.10.253.12) on the same host.
server listen on 0.0.0.0:2000,  client connect to 127.0.0.1:2000 or local eth ip:10.10.253.12:2000, CS transfer speed only 100KB per second.
Program writted by C using libevent and Java using Netty have the same effect, program writed as:

1. server accept connect, echo everything it recved.
2. client send arbitrary 128 byte data, when socket writable, send another 128 byte data; read and discard what it recved.

This couple client\server program work fine if run on different machine, speed at 30MB per second.

But zeromq pair communication by 127.0.0.1 have no such issue.

Server side code is:

```
---start listener
struct evconnlistener *listener = evconnlistener_new_bind(leader,
    listener_cb, NULL,
    LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE | LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE, s_backlog, &addr,
    addrlen);
if (!listener) {
    logit("Could not create a listener!");
    return 1;
}
int fd = evconnlistener_get_fd(listener);
int keepAlive = 0; // 非0值，开启keepalive属性
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&keepAlive, sizeof(keepAlive));
do{
    if (event_base_loop(leader, EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY) < 0){
        break;
    }
}while(!event_base_got_exit(leader));

---connect processing
static void listener_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, evutil_socket_t fd, struct sockaddr *sa, int socklen, void *user_data) {
    if (s_rcvbufsize > 0){
        setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void *)&s_rcvbufsize, sizeof(s_rcvbufsize));
    }
    if (s_sndbufsize > 0){
        setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (void *)&s_sndbufsize, sizeof(s_sndbufsize));
    }
    setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&s_tcpnodelay, sizeof(s_tcpnodelay));
    int keepAlive = 0;    // 非0值，开启keepalive属性
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&keepAlive, sizeof(keepAlive));

    struct bufferevent *bev = bufferevent_socket_new(s_worker, fd, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE|BEV_OPT_THREADSAFE);
    if (!bev) {
        logit("Error constructing bufferevent!");
        evutil_closesocket(fd);
        return;
    }
    bufferevent_setcb(bev, conn_readcb, conn_writecb, conn_eventcb, NULL);
    bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ);
}

---read\write processing
static void conn_writecb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *user_data) {
}
static void conn_readcb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *user_data) {
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    int len = evbuffer_get_length(input);

    struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(bev);
    evbuffer_add_buffer(output, input);
}
```

Client side code is:

```
---init connection
struct bufferevent* bev= bufferevent_socket_new(s_event_base, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE|BEV_OPT_THREADSAFE);
if (!bev){
    return 1;
}
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 30; //connect timeout
tv.tv_usec = 0;
bufferevent_set_timeouts(bev, NULL, &tv);
bufferevent_setcb(bev, NULL, NULL, connect_eventcb, (void*)s_event_base);
int flag = bufferevent_socket_connect(bev, &s_target_sockaddr, s_target_socklen);
if (-1 == flag ){
    bufferevent_free(bev);
    return 1;
}

---connected processing
static void connect_eventcb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *user_data) {
    if (events & (BEV_EVENT_EOF | BEV_EVENT_ERROR | BEV_EVENT_TIMEOUT)){
        bufferevent_free(bev);
    }else if (events & BEV_EVENT_CONNECTED) {
        int fd = bufferevent_getfd(bev);
        if (s_sorcvbufsize > 0){
            setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void *)&s_sorcvbufsize, sizeof(s_sorcvbufsize));
        }
        if (s_sosndbufsize > 0){
            setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (void *)&s_sosndbufsize, sizeof(s_sosndbufsize));
        }
        setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&s_tcpnodelay, sizeof(s_tcpnodelay));
        int keepAlive = 0;    // 非0值，开启keepalive属性
        setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&keepAlive, sizeof(keepAlive));

        bufferevent_setwatermark(bev, EV_WRITE, s_snd_wmark_l, s_snd_wmark_h);
        bufferevent_setcb(bev, conn_readcb, conn_writecb, conn_eventcb, NULL);

        bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);
        bufferevent_trigger(bev, EV_WRITE, BEV_TRIG_IGNORE_WATERMARKS|BEV_OPT_DEFER_CALLBACKS);
    }
}

---read/write processing
static void conn_writecb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *user_data) {
    struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(bev);
    for (int len = evbuffer_get_length(output); len < s_snd_wmark_h; len += s_sendsize){
        if (0 != bufferevent_write(bev, s_send_buf, s_sendsize)){
            break;
        }
    }
}
static void conn_readcb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *user_data) {
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    evbuffer_drain(input, 0x7FFFFFFF);
}
```

Tshark capture shows there is many KeepAliveReq no matter how SO_KEEPALIVE is setted:
[tshark capture result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iHTr.jpg)

[tshark capture result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r23z7.jpg)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS，CentOS 6，7 all have this issue。

Answer (score 0):

I tested and resolved it now:
the main reason is send buffer size of the server side is two small(8K), then the recv size, which cause server send congest.

When I adjust both buffer size to 32K, the problem disappeared.